# Fragment overlapping each other...and previous fragment is clicking

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I created an application in which i had **1 ACTIVITY** and **8 Fragment** in which i am inflating every fragment into the activity. but my problem is that every **fragment is overlapping each other**. I change the background color of every fragment but when i am clicking the vacant spaces button of my previous fragment get clicked.

please suggest me some thing to get out of this situation.

Main_Activity.class

```
public class ActRegistration extends AppCompatActivity {
    FragmentManager fm;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);
        fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        loadFragment(new FragmentRegLogSkip(), FragmentRegLogSkip.FRAGMENT_KEY);
    }


    public void loadFragment(Fragment fragmentName, String fragmentKey) {
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.id_registration_layout_frame, fragmentName);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(fragmentKey);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
}
```

Frag_1.class

```
public class FragmentRegLogSkip extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Activity activity;
    private Context context;
    public static final String FRAGMENT_KEY = "fragment_reg_log_skip";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getContext();
        LanguageChanger.changeLanguage(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.act_registration_screen_login, container, false);
return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `fragmentTransaction.add()`, which won't remove the previous Fragment - use `fragmentTransaction.replace()` if you want the other Fragment's view to be removed.

Note `FragmentManager` automatically restores any previously added Fragments when your Activity is recreated (i.e., when `savedInstanceState != null`). Therefore you'll want to ensure that you only add your initial Fragment once - when the `savedInstanceState` is null.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    loadFragment(new FragmentRegLogSkip(), FragmentRegLogSkip.FRAGMENT_KEY);
}
```

Comment: but sir there is one problem previous from data is not there ... :(

Comment: That sounds like an entirely separate question, so I'd encourage you to create an entirely separate question with what you're currently seeing and what you want to see

Answer (score 8):

Don't forget to add `android:clickable="true"` and  `android:focusable="true"` to the parent view of your second fragment so it catches the clicks and they don't get propagated to the fragment below. Something like this:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true">
```

Comment: what will happen with this??

Comment: what if i back press and get the same screen like a-->b   then back press will buttons in a will work??\

Comment: add above code in your both of fragment and also if you are using add method instead of replace then add solid background in a view. so that both fragment don't overlap.

Comment: already shared its the same code i already tick the right answer.. and your answer is not working.. as you suggested i added those 2 line in every fragment but it didn't work

Comment: i faced same issue and it worked for me. share your xml code.

Comment: i didn't use solid background rather i use background color but the answer which i accepted worked for me

Comment: Worked for me very Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Inside your second fragment layout file's Parent Tag , add this :-

```
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
```

then when you click on any view , it will not click previous fragment.

Comment: will it work on 8 fragment on top of each other and when i backpress and get back to previous fragment will click event still work for the top fragment

Comment: yes it will work , use this and feel free to upvote and accept.

Comment: not working i added this lines in parent layout xml of every fragment but not working